# navigation drawer fragment and tablayout fragment overlapping

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

Navigation drawer fragment and tablayout fragment is overlapping each other because of these when we open navigation drawer fragment we also see the content of tablayout fragment so i have added a screen shot below can you help me to solve this problem i have mentioned xml file below so please solve my problem

activity_main.xml

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/naviview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navi_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_item" />


  </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

app_bar.xml

```
`<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pageviewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tablayout"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`

Mainactivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    toolbar()

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerlayout, R.string.open, 
  R.string.close)
    drawerlayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()



    naviview.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.add_book -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, Addbook())
                    .addToBackStack("Addbook")
                    .commit()
                supportActionBar?.title = "Addbooks"
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers()
            }
            R.id.add_bookset -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, Addbooksets())
                    .addToBackStack("Addbooksets")
                    .commit()
                supportActionBar?.title = "Addbooksets"
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers()
            }
            R.id.add_tools -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, AddTools())
                    .addToBackStack("AddTools")
                    .commit()
                supportActionBar?.title = "AddTools"
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers()
            }
            R.id.About_App -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, Aboutus())
                    .addToBackStack("Aboutus")
                    .commit()
                supportActionBar?.title = "About us"
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers()
            }
            R.id.contact_us -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, Contactus())
                    .addToBackStack("Contactus")
                    .commit()
                supportActionBar?.title = "Contact us"
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers()
            }
            R.id.share_app -> Toast.makeText(this, " Share app 
    selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            R.id.logout -> Toast.makeText(this, "Logout selected", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        true
    }
    setfragments()
 }

 private fun setfragments() {
     val adapter = viewpageadapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addfragment(Books(), "Books")
    adapter.addfragment(BookSets(), "BookSets")
    adapter.addfragment(Tools(), "Tools")
    pageviewer.adapter = adapter
    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(pageviewer)

  }

   fun toolbar() {
    var toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.title="BookQueen"
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
  }

   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
   }
   }
```

viewpageadapter.kt

```
class viewpageadapter(supportfragmentmanger:FragmentManager):
 FragmentPagerAdapter(supportfragmentmanger,
BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
private val fragmentlist= ArrayList<Fragment>()
private val fragmenttitlelist= ArrayList<String>()

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentlist[position]
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
   return fragmentlist.size
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return fragmenttitlelist[position]
}

fun addfragment(fragment: Fragment,title:String){
    fragmentlist.add(fragment)
    fragmenttitlelist.add(title)
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to add fragments in activity

Comment: Sir i have added mainactivity and fragment adapter  code in question can you plz solve my error

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't understand why you have written the code like that. The general pattern involving a tab layout and drawer is to have a drawer fragment contain a tab layout and its fragments as child fragment. So what you need to do here is separate the tab bar layout and viewpager from `app_bar.xml` and write them inside their own xml as they should be inside their own fragment. Also inside that fragment keep the viewpager below tablayout and replace this newly created fragment when the appropriate drawer option is selected.